Convergence for the Proximal Point Algorithm
I have been looking into convergence guarantees for the proximal point algorithm (PPA):
\begin{equation}
x^{i+1}=\mathcal{J}_{\alpha f}(x^{i}),
\end{equation}
where $f$ is a closed convex function and the proximal operator is:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{J}_{f}=(I+\partial f)^{-1},
\end{equation}
with $\partial f$ being the subdifferential of $f$. It is known that $\mathcal{J}_{\alpha f}$ with $\alpha>0$ is firmly non-expansive, and I found some sources that claim that PPA weakly converges to a fixed point of the proximal operator. For instance, Section 6 in [1], the discussion on the third page of [2], and the line after Equation (6) in [3].
On the other hand, it is also known that the PPA step above can be written as the optimization problem:
\begin{equation}
x^{i+1}=\arg \min_{x}\left(f(x)+\frac{1}{2\alpha}\|{x-x^i}\|_{2}^{2}\right)~,
\end{equation}
which has been shown to strongly converge into a fixed point
Proof of Convergence for the Proximal Point Algorithm.
could someone help me understand what I am missing here?
Why do all these papers only talk about weak convergence if strong convergence holds in this case?
Thank you.
[1] Kohsaka, Fumiaki, and Wataru Takahashi. "Existence and approximation of fixed points of firmly nonexpansive-type mappings in Banach spaces." SIAM journal on optimization 19.2 (2008): 824-835.
[2] Rockafellar, R. Tyrrell. "Monotone operators and the proximal point algorithm." SIAM journal on control and optimization 14.5 (1976): 877-898.
[3] Bauschke, Heinz H., Sarah M. Moffat, and Xianfu Wang. "Firmly nonexpansive mappings and maximally monotone operators: correspondence and duality." Set-Valued and Variational Analysis 20 (2012): 131-153.

To answer your question, the proximal point algorithm converges weakly in Hilbert spaces, and we know that it does not converge strongly in general. A counter-example was found by O. Güler [1] (based on a counter-example designed by J.-B. Baillon for dynamical systems [2]).
So the confusion in your question comes from the other MSE you are pointing to. Contrary to what you read, they do not prove the strong convergence of the PPA. All I can see is a sort of proof of convergence for the values $f(x_k)$, not the iterates themselves. And they assume at some point that $X$ is compact, which is not very compatible with infinite dimension.
I assume in my answer that you know that in finite dimensional spaces weak and strong convergence are the same.
[1] O. Güler: On the convergence of the proximal point algorithm for convex minimization, SIAM J. Control Optimization 29 (1991) 403–419.
[2] J.-B. Baillon: Un exemple concernant le comportement asymptotique de la solution du problème du/dt + ∂ϕ(u) = 0, J. Funct. Anal. 28 (1978) 369–376.

Thank you for the reply!
I am fairly new to this and I failed to notice that weak and strong convergence are the same in finite dimension (which I am mostly interested in). Nevertheless, it will be beneficial for me to know that for general Hilbert spaces things are different.
